# React pdf responsiveness using React Hooks, but when increasing or decreasing window size I get this TypeError

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-pdf

```
import React, { useState, useRef, useEffect } from 'react';
import throttle from 'lodash/throttle';
import { Document, Page } from 'react-pdf/dist/esm/entry.webpack';
import 'react-pdf/dist/esm/Page/AnnotationLayer.css';

export default function PDFWrapper({ data, onDocumentLoadSuccess, pageNumber }) {
  const [initialWidth, setInitialWidth] = useState(null);
  const pdfWrapper = useRef();

  const setPdfSize = () => {
    setInitialWidth(pdfWrapper.current.getBoundingClientRect().width);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('resize', throttle(setPdfSize, 3000));
    setPdfSize();
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('resize', throttle(setPdfSize, 3000));
    };
  });

  return (
    <div
      id="row"
      style={{
        height: '100vh', display: 'flex',
      }}
    >
      <div id="placeholderWrapper" style={{ height: '100vh' }} />
      <div id="pdfWrapper" style={{ width: '90vw' }} ref={pdfWrapper}>
        <Document
          file={data}
          onLoadSuccess={onDocumentLoadSuccess}
          noData=""
          loading=""
        >
          <Page pageNumber={pageNumber} loading="" width={initialWidth} />
        </Document>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I will copy here the whole error. It looks like it is coming from setPdfSize function.
NOTE:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'getBoundingClientRect' of null.
> 10 | const setPdfSize = () => {
> 11 |   setInitialWidth(pdfWrapper.current.getBoundingClientRect().width);
> | ^  12 | };
> 13 |
> 14 | useEffect(() => {
> Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly I would add `[]` an empty dependency array to `useEffect` hook in order to run only once the component is mounted, probably you don't want to attach and detach several times the same event. Also I would check for `null` values at `setPdfSize` function because it's initially `null`.

See from the [`useRef`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref) documentation:

> `useRef` returns a mutable ref object whose `.current` property is initialized to the passed argument (initialValue). The returned object will persist for the full lifetime of the component.

I would try as the following:

```
const pdfWrapper = useRef(null);

const setPdfSize = () => {
  if (pdfWrapper && pdfWrapper.current) {
    setInitialWidth(pdfWrapper.current.getBoundingClientRect().width);
  }
};

useEffect(() => {
  window.addEventListener('resize', throttle(setPdfSize, 3000));
  setPdfSize();
  return () => {
    window.removeEventListener('resize', throttle(setPdfSize, 3000));
  };
}, []);
```

Comment: @DragoJokera Awesome, happy to help! Please consider accepting or upvoting as the answer for your question if it worked, Thank you!